# Calculating Expected Value With Matrix Values

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, matrix-multiplication

I have the following input data

```
class_p = [0.0234375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1748046875, 0.0439453125, 0.0, 0.35302734375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3828125]
league_p =  [0.4765625, 0.0, 0.00634765625, 0.4658203125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.046875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0029296875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
a2_p = [0.1171875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1171875, 0.0, 0.0078125, 0.30322265625, 0.31103515625, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1435546875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
p1_p = [0.0, 0.03125, 0.375, 0.09375, 0.0234375, 0.0, 0.46875, 0.0078125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
p2_p = [0.3984375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3828125, 0.08935546875, 0.08935546875, 0.023345947265625, 0.007720947265625, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0087890625, 0.00018310546875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

class_v = [55, 75, 55, 75, 500, 10000, 55, 55, 55, 75, 75, 55, 55, 500, 55, 55, 75, 75, 55, 55, 55]
league_v = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 40, 40, 40, 1500, 1500, 3000]
a2_v= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 40, 40, 40, 1500, 1500, 3000]
p1_v = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 1500, 1500, 3000]
p2_v = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 40, 40, 40, 1500, 1500, 3000]
```

With that data, I am generating the odds of each combination occurring.

As an example to generate the chance of a given combination

```
class_p[0] 
league_p[6]
a2_p[11]
p1_p[7]
p2_p[3]
```

I would multiply their values with each other
`0.0234375x0.046875x0.1435546875x0.0078125x0.3828125`

That would give me `4.716785042546689510345458984375 × 10^-7`

Since the given combination had `class_p[0], league_p[6], a2_p[11], p1_p[7], p2_p[3]`, I would take the following values in the "values" arrays.
I would sum

`class_v[0] + league_v[6] + a2_v[11] + p1_v[7] + p2_v[3]`
That would give me `55+0+40+40+0 = 135`

To finalize the process I would do
`(0.0234375*0.046875*0.1435546875*0.0078125*0.3828125)*(55+0+40+40+0) = 0.00006367659807`

The full final calc is
`(0.0234375×0.046875×0.1435546875×0.0078125×0.3828125) (55 + 0 + 40 + 40 + 0)`
`(combintation_chance)*(combination_value)`
I need to do this process for all possible combinations of `combintation_chance`

This should give me a column of values(1xN). If I sum the values of that column I reach the EV overall, by summing the EV of individual combinations.

Calculating `combintation_chance` is working just fine. My issue is how to line up the given combination with its corresponding value sum (`combination_value`). At the moment, I have additional identifiers attached to the `*_p` arrays and I then do a string comparison with them to determine which `combination` value to use. This is very slow for billions of comparisons, therefore I am exploring a better approach.

I am using python 3.8 & numpy 1.24

**Edit**

The question has been adjusted to include much more detail

Comment: This seems like a single call to `np.outer`. Have you tried that?

Comment: My main issue lies in confirming that `class_percentages[4] AND league_percentages[4]` should be aligned with `value_5` and that e.g. `class_percentages[2] AND league_percentages[3]` should not. Once I figure out a way to do that, I think that `np.outer` is the right way to append that information.

Comment: It is an integer. Anywhere from 50-5000. It is also a user defined, static value.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Originally, I wanted to give a simpler version of the problem but I've realized that leaving out the details didn't do anyone any favors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251978/discussion-between-adam-and-reinderien).

Comment: So, what is the expected result in your example?

Comment: @chrslg I've updated the question to provide a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Are you sure of your example? `p1_v[7]` shoud be, 0, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Broadcasting

Ok, so it seems that this is a simple broadcasting problem.

You want a 5D-array of probabilities, times a 5d-array of values. And, of course, you want it without any for loop.

In numpy the classical way to have numpy do nested loops for you (which is, indeed, way faster than doing them yourself. First rule of numpy is "avoid at all cost to iterate over elements. No for loop"), is to use broadcasting.

Let's start with 2d example (as was your first intention. And that was a good idea. Problem was it was ambiguous, but restraining your question to 2d was not bad).

You have

```py
class_p = np.array([0.0234375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1748046875, 0.0439453125, 0.0, 0.35302734375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3828125])
league_p =  np.array([0.4765625, 0.0, 0.00634765625, 0.4658203125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.046875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0029296875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
```

One way (not the only one, but probably the one easier to adapt to any similar question) is to use broadcasting.

If you indeed convert `class_p` in a column, that is a 21×1 2D array, and `league_p` into a line, that is a 1×15 2D array, then, if you multiply both, result will be a 21x15 2D array, containing all combinations.

Because

```py
np.array([[1],[2],[3]]) * np.array([[4,5]])
```

is

```
[[4,5],
 [8,10],
 [12,15]]
```

That's how broadcasting works.

There are several way to convert a 1D-array so a row or a column of a 2D-array. For example you could use `.reshape`. Like `class_p.reshape(-1,1)` and `league_p.reshape(1,-1)`. But the fastest is to add a new axis. Like `class_p[:,None]` and `league_p[None,:]`. Note that the second way doesn't really create a new array. It is just a different view of the same array. This is way it is faster.

So, our 2D probability map is

```py
class_p[:,None]*league_p[None,:]
```

Likewise, to have all 21×15 combination of sum of values, you can rely on the same broadcasting to perform additon

```py
class_v[:,None]+league_v[None,:]
```

### Broadcasting solution

So solution, in 2D, using broadcasting, is

```py
class_p[:,None]*league_p[None,:] * (class_v[:,None] + league_v[None,:])
```

In 5D, with all your variables, it is still manageable (but don't add too much dimensions! it would soon become a huge result. And I suspect what you are really interested at the end is just the sum of all that), this time, not in one line (not that it couldn't be done that way, but, that would be a big line...)

```py
pr = class_p[:,None,None,None,None]*league_p[None,:,None,None,None]*a2_p[None,None,:,None,None]*p1_p[None,None,None,:,None]*p2_p[None,None,None,None,:]
vl = class_v[:,None,None,None,None]+league_v[None,:,None,None,None]+a2_v[None,None,:,None,None]+p1_v[None,None,None,:,None]+p2_v[None,None,None,None,:]
pr*vl
```

## add.outer and multiply.outer

As you can see, in 5D, it is a little bit tedious. But I wanted to show you the principle of broadcasting, before introducing another (not really shorter, but a bit less tedious) way. Way that was already given by Reinderien. But since it was before you clarified the question, it was not the good result, but principle is the same

In 2D

```py
np.multiply.outer(class_p, league_p) * np.add.outer(class_v, league_v)
```

Unfortunately, those function take only 2 args. So in 5D, you have to chain them

```py
pr = np.multiply.outer(class_p, np.multiply.outer(league_p, np.multiply.outer(a2_p, np.multiply.outer(p1_p, p2_p))))
vl = np.add.outer(class_v, np.add.outer(league_v, np.add.outer(a2_v, np.add.outer(p1_v, p2_v))))
pr * vl
```

## Expected value

Note that if the aim of all this is to compute the expected "value" (whatever that value is), that is Σ p(i,j,k,l,m)×v(i,j,k,l,m), for all possible outcomes, then, doing it that way is probably not a good idea.

For your example, it is manageable. You are computing "only" 1 million possible outcomes that is 1 million probabilities (each of them being 4 multiplications) and 1 million associated values (4 additions each). And the performing 1 million multiplication between those 2 sets of 1 million probabilities and values. And then summing the result, that is one extra million addition. Altogether, that is only 10 millions elementary arithmetic operation. Not much for a modern computer, and response still feels instantaneous. But, yet, it is O(Nᵏ) is both cpu and memory. N being the typical length of an array, and k the number of variables.

But if you intend to add more dimensions (more variables, associated with more set of probabilities and set of values), then that is unnecessary explosive, in both CPU time, and memory (those 5D arrays of probabilities and values are stored), or simply if you intend to perform this computation more than once, that expected value can be computed way faster, using just O(Nk) operations.

I spare you the development (but it is just a matter of expanding sum Σᵢⱼₖₗₘ pᵢpⱼpₖpₗpₘ (vᵢ+vⱼ+vₖ+vₗ+vₘ)), you can compute it faster like this

```py
P1 = class_p.sum()
PV1 = (class_p*class_v).sum()
P2 = league_p.sum()
PV2 = (league_p*league_v).sum()
P3 = a2_p.sum()
PV3 = (a2_p*a2_v).sum()
P4 = p1_p.sum()
PV4 = (p1_p*p1_v).sum()
P5 = p2_p.sum()
PV5 = (p2_p*p2_v).sum()
expectedValue = P1*P2*P3*P4*PV5 + P1*P2*P3*PV4*P5 + P1*P2*PV3*P4*P5 + P1*PV2*P3*P4*P5 + PV1*P2*P3*P4*P5
sameAs = (pr*vl).sum()
```

It appears more complicated because there are more lines. But each line is along 1 dimension only. So it is replacing an order of magnitude of n₁n₂n₃n₄n₅ operations by an order of magnitude of n₁+n₂+n₃+n₄+n₅ operations, where n₁,...,n₅ are the size of arrays of each of the 5 variables.

So, again, if your objective is to compute expected value, then, trying to compute the 5D arrays (as your question is), is a really costly way.

Comment: Great explanation. I'm happy I posed the question, because I've actually learned a lot along the way.
Your proposed solution(s) works. I implemented two of them 1) the outer based and 2) the summation based. 
I will eventually add more dimensions to the calculation, so I opted for the summation which was already recognizably quicker. What had taken me ~15hours to compute using string comparisons and deeply nested for loops, is now complete in under 6 min.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make any attempt to cache intermediate results, etc.

```py
import numpy as np

class_percentages  = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.50)
league_percentages = (0.1, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05)
class_values = (50, 50, 50, 75, 100)
league_values = (0, 10, 10, 25, 75)
combined = np.add.outer(class_percentages, league_percentages)*np.add.outer(class_values, league_values)

print(combined)
```

Output:

```
[[ 5.    0.   12.    7.5   6.25]
 [ 5.    0.   12.    7.5   6.25]
 [ 5.    0.   12.    7.5   6.25]
 [30.   25.5  42.5  40.   52.5 ]
 [60.   55.   77.   75.   96.25]]
```

Comment: I left out some information in the original problem. I realize it is relevant now. Original post has been edited.

Comment: It's late here - I've not been paying close attention to detail. I need to multiply class_percentages and league_percentages and not sum them. I am guessing I can just do np.multiply(class_percentages, league_percentages) * np.add.outer(...)?
Does this structure still hold if the number of *_percentages arrays increases, but use the same *_value arrays?

Comment: @Adam Again, provide full example. Your example is useless if it doesn't come with expected result.

Comment: @chrslg I've adjusted the question. I believe it should provide adequate information now.